# Plot graph from - to specified indices

Tags: matlab

I have a `1x5000 matrix` we can call `exampleMatrix`, that is filled with numbers. These numbers have indices, my question is: How do I plot a line of numbers with indices starting from 100 to 450 for instance? The rest should get excluded (not plotted).

Right now I just `plot(exampleMatrix, 'b')`.

Comment: Maybe `plot(exampleMatrix(100:450), 'b')` is what you want? Or is another thing?

Comment: A better way might be to use the original plot line, and then `xlim([100 450]);`.  Doing this means that should you wish to extend the range, or zoom in using the Edit tools, the data will all be there.  It also means that the x-axis labels will be consistent whatever section of the plot is displayed.